# How to push my div down on the bottom of my header

Tags: html, css

Friends, I have a div with text inside my header, but I want to push that div so it rests on the bottom of my header window. what would be the best way to do it, thank you very much in advance.
So far it looks like this:

```css
#head {
  border: solid black 1px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("../images/interior1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #f8f6f0;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="head">
    <div id="text">
      <h1>Nagoya Express</h1>
      <p>
        <h2>Your Way to More Ecofriendly and Economical Personal Trasportation</h2>
      </p>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: can you make a codepen? and explain what should be on the bottom ? "Nagoya Express?"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you have two the best options:

1. Add position: relative for #head and position: absolute for #text. And to next you need set bottom: 0; for #text.
2. Second option is using display: flex for #head and set align-items: flex-end.

Both solutions are presented in the example below:

```css
.head {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.text {
  background: green;
}

.head--position {
  position: relative;
}

.head--position .text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.head--flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="head head--position">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Nagoya Express</h1>
        <p>Your Way to More Ecofriendly and Economical Personal Trasportation</p>
    </div>
  </header>
  <header class="head head--flex">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Nagoya Express</h1>
        <p>Your Way to More Ecofriendly and Economical Personal Trasportation</p>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

It is good to pay attention to the fact **that selectors should be styled by the class, not by the id**.